# Canvas signature to be saved on server (PHP)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, canvas

I try to save the PNG file from a signature drawn in a canva. I can't find out where the bug is. I don't get any error message and nothing happens, no file is created in the /img folder.
Could you please help me?
Many thanks!

**index.html**

```
<html>
     <head>
          <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
          <script src="../scripts/signature.js"></script>    
     </head>
     <body>    
          <div id="canvas">
               <canvas class="roundCorners" id="newSignature" style="position: relative; margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 1px solid #c4caac;">
               </canvas>
          </div>

  <script>
        signatureCapture();
  </script>

          <button type="button" onclick="signatureSave()">Save signature</button>
          <button type="button" onclick="signatureClear()">Clear signature</button>
          </br>
          <img id="saveSignature" alt="Saved image png"/>
     </body>
</html>
```

**signature.js**

```
  var canvas = document.getElementById("newSignature");
  var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

if (!context) {
  throw new Error("Failed to get canvas' 2d context");
}

  canvas.width = 474 ;
  canvas.height = 314 ;

  context.fillStyle = "#fff";
  context.strokeStyle = "#444";
  context.lineWidth = 1.2;
  context.lineCap = "round";

  context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  context.fillStyle = "#3a87ad";
  context.strokeStyle = "#3a87ad";
  context.lineWidth = 1;
  context.moveTo(20,220);
  context.lineTo(454,220);
  context.stroke();

  context.fillStyle = "#fff";
  context.strokeStyle = "#444";


  var disableSave = true;
  var pixels = [];
  var cpixels = [];
  var xyLast = {};
  var xyAddLast = {};
  var calculate = false;

//functions
{
    function remove_event_listeners() {
        canvas.removeEventListener('mousemove', on_mousemove, false);
        canvas.removeEventListener('mouseup', on_mouseup, false);
        canvas.removeEventListener('touchmove', on_mousemove, false);
        canvas.removeEventListener('touchend', on_mouseup, false);

        document.body.removeEventListener('mouseup', on_mouseup, false);
        document.body.removeEventListener('touchend', on_mouseup, false);
}

    function get_board_coords(e) {
        var x, y;

        if (e.changedTouches && e.changedTouches[0]) {
            var offsety = canvas.offsetTop || 0;
            var offsetx = canvas.offsetLeft || 0;

            x = e.changedTouches[0].pageX - offsetx;
            y = e.changedTouches[0].pageY - offsety;
        } 
        else if (e.layerX || 0 == e.layerX) {
            x = e.layerX;
            y = e.layerY;
        } 
        else if (e.offsetX || 0 == e.offsetX) {
            x = e.offsetX;
            y = e.offsetY;
        }

        return {
            x : x,
            y : y
        };
    };

    function on_mousedown(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();

        canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', on_mousemove, false);
        canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', on_mouseup, false);
        canvas.addEventListener('touchmove', on_mousemove, false);
        canvas.addEventListener('touchend', on_mouseup, false);

        document.body.addEventListener('mouseup', on_mouseup, false);
        document.body.addEventListener('touchend', on_mouseup, false);

        empty = false;
        var xy = get_board_coords(e);
        context.beginPath();
        pixels.push('moveStart');
        context.moveTo(xy.x, xy.y);
        pixels.push(xy.x, xy.y);
        xyLast = xy;
    };

    function on_mousemove(e, finish) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();

        var xy = get_board_coords(e);
        var xyAdd = {
            x : (xyLast.x + xy.x) / 2,
            y : (xyLast.y + xy.y) / 2
        };

        if (calculate) {
            var xLast = (xyAddLast.x + xyLast.x + xyAdd.x) / 3;
            var yLast = (xyAddLast.y + xyLast.y + xyAdd.y) / 3;
            pixels.push(xLast, yLast);
        } else {
            calculate = true;
        }

        context.quadraticCurveTo(xyLast.x, xyLast.y, xyAdd.x, xyAdd.y);
        pixels.push(xyAdd.x, xyAdd.y);
        context.stroke();
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(xyAdd.x, xyAdd.y);
        xyAddLast = xyAdd;
        xyLast = xy;

    };

    function on_mouseup(e) {
        remove_event_listeners();
        disableSave = false;
        context.stroke();
        pixels.push('e');
        calculate = false;
    };

}//end

    canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', on_mousedown, false);
    canvas.addEventListener('touchstart', on_mousedown, false);
}

    function signatureSave() {

        var canvas = document.getElementById("newSignature");
        // save canvas image as data url (png format by default)
        var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        document.getElementById("saveSignature").src = dataURL;

        var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
        ajax.open("POST",'./saveSignature.php',false);
        ajax.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/upload');
        ajax.send(dataURL); 

    };

    function signatureClear() {
        var canvas = document.getElementById("newSignature");
        var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
        context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    }

}
```

**saveSignature.php**

```
    $result = array();
    $imagedata = base64_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
    $filename = md5(date("dmYhisA"));
    //Location to where you want to created sign image
    $file_name = './img/'.$filename.'.png';
    file_put_contents($file_name,$imagedata);
    $result['status'] = 1;
    $result['file_name'] = $file_name;
    echo json_encode($result);
?>
```

There is no issue with the drawing of the signature. The only problem is how to save on the server the PNG file made from the data coming the canva.

Comment: Have you checked if there's an actual request taking place under your browser's development tools?

Comment: What debugging have you done to determine that the issue is on the server? Also, you should indent your code properly. It's really hard to follow the flow when there's none at all. Specially when you've posted that much code.

Comment: You're not fetching the data correctly in PHP. There won't be any `$_POST['dataURL']` since that property is never set in the request body. You're just passing the data "as is" without a key. Try fetching it in PHP with: `file_get_contents('php://input')` instead of `$_POST['dataURL']`.

Comment: Thanks Magnus and Mats for your input. Magnus, I indented the code as you mentionned and replaced the $_POST['dateUTL'] with the file_get_contents('php://input'). I tried it but so far it doesn't work. Mats, I don't know how to check if there is an actual request taking place in my browser (I'm beginner :-) )